# Finding the pdf of a random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with the distribution:

$$f(x) = \frac{g(a+b)}{g(a)g(b)} x^{a-1} (1-x〗^{b-1}~, \quad0<x<1$$
where $g(c) = c$! and $a$ and $b$ are known fixed values.
I want to find the pdf of the random variable $((1/x)-1)$

So I don't have a lot so far, I know that if I can find the cdf of $\frac{1}{x}-1$, I can differentiate to find the pdf but that's about all. I'm really stuck here.

Comment: Your expression for $f(x)$ is not correct. it should be $g(c) = \Gamma(c)$.

Comment: Yes I know but I couldn't type gamma (new to this site so still figuring everything out).

Answer (score 1):

For $t>0$ we have
$$
\left\{\frac1X-1\leqslant t\right\} = \left\{X\geqslant \frac1{1+t} \right\},
$$
and hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(\frac1X-1\leqslant t\right) &= 1- \mathbb P\left(X\leqslant\frac1{1+t}\right)\\
&=1 - I_{\frac1{1+t}}(a,b)\\
&=1- \frac{B\left(\frac1{1+t};a,b\right)}{B(a,b)}\\
&=1 - \frac{B_{\frac{1}{t+1}}(a,b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)/\Gamma(a+b)}.
\end{align}
Differentiating yields the density of $\frac1X-1$:
$$
\frac{\left(\frac{1}{t+1}\right)^a t^{b-1} (t+1)^{-b} \Gamma (a+b)}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (b)},\quad t>0.
$$